# Integrating Google Docs Drawing into Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, google-docs

Alfresco is integrated with Google Docs, so that Alfresco users can easily create or edit a document/spreadsheet/presentation using Google's online editors:

[image]

For images, it sounds like [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings) could be used.

How to allow Alfresco users to create/edit PNG/etc graphic files from Alfresco, by using Google Docs?

is it just a matter of activating the menu item in some configuration file, or would it require me to implement the feature (probably by looking at the source code for Google Documents), or is it downright impossible due to some technical difficulty I have not thought about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not one of the available integrations, but I guess you can write that yourself, as the repository is now avaible at https://github.com/Alfresco/googledrive